# XSLT - Show different node data on each line (atm the first node is shown on all lines)

Tags: xslt

I have a problem with showing the correct info in all nodes. I just get the first node, in all the nodes...

Have tried several different, but can not get it correct. First week in into my XSLT traning, so slowly getting there :P

Hope anybody can tell me what I'm doing wrong here. Thank you in advance :)

EDIT: I'm trying to divide the GrossMass based on the NetMass.

Parts of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Job xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
  <Invoice>
    <TotGrossMass>1853.80</TotGrossMass>
    <TotNetMass>1752.00</TotNetMass>
    <InvoiceLine>
      <LineNo>1</LineNo>
      <GrossMass></GrossMass>
      <NetMass>212.3</NetMass>
    </InvoiceLine>
    <InvoiceLine>
      <LineNo>2</LineNo>
      <GrossMass></GrossMass>
      <NetMass>212.3</NetMass>
    </InvoiceLine>
    <InvoiceLine>
      <LineNo>3</LineNo>
      <GrossMass></GrossMass>
      <NetMass>227.4</NetMass>
    </InvoiceLine>
    <InvoiceLine>
      <LineNo>4</LineNo>
      <GrossMass></GrossMass>
      <NetMass>550</NetMass>
    </InvoiceLine>
    <InvoiceLine>
      <LineNo>5</LineNo>
      <GrossMass></GrossMass>
      <NetMass>550</NetMass>
    </InvoiceLine>
  </Invoice>
</Job>
```

Parts of the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:element name="Job">

        <xsl:element name="Invoice">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Job/Invoice/TotGrossMass"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Job/Invoice/TotNetMass"/>
          <xsl:for-each select="Job/Invoice/InvoiceLine">
            <xsl:element name="InvoiceLine">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="LineNo"/>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="GrossMass"/>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="NetMass"/>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="GrossMass">
      <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(ancestor::Invoice/InvoiceLine/NetMass * ancestor::Invoice/TotGrossMass div ancestor::Invoice/TotNetMass,'#.##')"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Job xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
      <Invoice>
       <TotGrossMass>1853.80</TotGrossMass>
       <TotNetMass>1752.00</TotNetMass>
       <InvoiceLine>
          <LineNo>1</LineNo>
          <GrossMass>224.64</GrossMass>
          <NetMass>212.3</NetMass>
       </InvoiceLine>
       <InvoiceLine>
          <LineNo>2</LineNo>
          <GrossMass>224.64</GrossMass>
          <NetMass>212.3</NetMass>
       </InvoiceLine>
       <InvoiceLine>
          <LineNo>3</LineNo>
          <GrossMass>224.64</GrossMass>
          <NetMass>227.4</NetMass>
       </InvoiceLine>
       <InvoiceLine>
          <LineNo>4</LineNo>
          <GrossMass>224.64</GrossMass>
          <NetMass>550</NetMass>
       </InvoiceLine>
       <InvoiceLine>
          <LineNo>5</LineNo>
          <GrossMass>224.64</GrossMass>
          <NetMass>550</NetMass>
       </InvoiceLine>
     </Invoice>
   </Job>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are always receiving the value from the first node is because the following `ancestor` axis, `ancestor::Invoice/InvoiceLine/NetMass` is always using the value from the first node.

The XSLT can be simplified by using a different approach. The input and output XML structure is pretty much the same. In such a case, it is advisable to use the `identity template` which copies all the input XML nodes/attributes to the output as is.

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, the `GrossMass` needs to be updated based on some calculation. In order to do that, override the `GrossMass` template and perform the computations. Store the `TotGrossMass` and `TotNetMass` into variables. Similarly, store the sibling `NetMass` value in another variable. Storing values in variables is just for ease of understanding as the equations become more readable.

```
<xsl:template match="GrossMass">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="totGrossMass" select="ancestor::Invoice/TotGrossMass" />
        <xsl:variable name="totNetMass" select="ancestor::Invoice/TotNetMass" />
        <xsl:variable name="netMass" select="../NetMass" />
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(($netMass * $totGrossMass) div $totNetMass, '#.##')" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The complete XSLT is as below

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="GrossMass">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="totGrossMass" select="ancestor::Invoice/TotGrossMass" />
            <xsl:variable name="totNetMass" select="ancestor::Invoice/TotNetMass" />
            <xsl:variable name="netMass" select="../NetMass" />
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(($netMass * $totGrossMass) div $totNetMass, '#.##')" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<Job xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Invoice>
        <TotGrossMass>1853.80</TotGrossMass>
        <TotNetMass>1752.00</TotNetMass>
        <InvoiceLine>
            <LineNo>1</LineNo>
            <GrossMass>224.64</GrossMass>
            <NetMass>212.3</NetMass>
        </InvoiceLine>
        <InvoiceLine>
            <LineNo>2</LineNo>
            <GrossMass>224.64</GrossMass>
            <NetMass>212.3</NetMass>
        </InvoiceLine>
        <InvoiceLine>
            <LineNo>3</LineNo>
            <GrossMass>240.61</GrossMass>
            <NetMass>227.4</NetMass>
        </InvoiceLine>
        <InvoiceLine>
            <LineNo>4</LineNo>
            <GrossMass>581.96</GrossMass>
            <NetMass>550</NetMass>
        </InvoiceLine>
        <InvoiceLine>
            <LineNo>5</LineNo>
            <GrossMass>581.96</GrossMass>
            <NetMass>550</NetMass>
        </InvoiceLine>
    </Invoice>
</Job>
```